# 'PowerShell' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

I have just installed Chocolatey via PowerShell, I tried running PowerShell both as myself and as administrator, and if I try running choco or cinst I get the following error:

```
PS C:\> choco /?
'PowerShell' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What do I do? I have a feeling this is related to more than just Chocolatey...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can happen if a program is not on your PATH. Open a PowerShell prompt and
enter

```sh
[environment]::setEnvironmentVariable('PATH',
"$env:path;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0", 'm')
```

then restart PowerShell.

Comment: this is not working for me. The error persists even after trying multiple times with PS both as administrator and user.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686206.aspx says "This function has no effect on the system environment variables or the environment variables of other processes." See http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_env_path.htm how to permanently modify environment variable via registry

Answer (score 2):

I found this helpful.

- Write cmd in the start menu, right-click and run as administrator.
- Then in the cmd, paste in this to install choco

> @powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex
>   ((new-object
>   net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))"
>   && SET PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin

Answer (score 2):

Put Chocolatey on the path.

Edit the system environmental variable. Go to

*System Properties* → *Advanced* → *Environment Variables* → *System variables* → *PATH* → *Edit* → *New*

Look for where Chocolatey is. In my case it was at `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey`.
Enter that, don't forget to put "\" after Chocolatey. I.e., it should be:
`C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\`

Comment: The only solution that worked for me after losing all PATH variables